# Distributed microservices using Kite and Kontrol

Tags: go, etcd, kite

I am able to register my kite microservice to kontrol but unable to discover it,

```
kites, err := k.GetKites(&protocol.KontrolQuery{
        Username:    k.Config.Username,
        Environment:k.Config.Environment,
        Name:"myservice",
    })enter code here
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("has error")
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
```

I am getting authenticationError.

```
has error
2015/06/16 09:59:16 authenticationError: token contains an invalid number of segments
exit status 1
```

Also I am not able to find `$USER_HOME/.kite/kite.key` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured it out. I need to export these environment variable,

```
export KONTROL_PORT=4099
export KONTROL_USERNAME="kontrol"
export KONTROL_STORAGE="etcd"
export KONTROL_KONTROLURL="http://127.0.0.1:4099/kite"
export KONTROL_PUBLICKEYFILE=~/certs/key_pub.pem
export KONTROL_PRIVATEKEYFILE=~/certs/key.pem
```

Then generate rsa token,

```
cd ~/certs/
openssl genrsa -out key.pem 2048
openssl rsa -in key.pem -pubout > key_pub.pem
openssl rsa -in key.pem -pubout > key_pub.pem
```

Run Kontrol CLI with -install flag.

Comment: Hi, I'm also trying to get kontrol work... but I've a few problems. I've created the keys, set the environment variables, and started etcd... but when I start kontrol I always get the following error message: `[kontrol] CRITICAL Could not create KitesPrefix "/kites": client: etcd cluster is unavailable or misconfigured; error #0: unsupported protocol scheme ""`. May I ask you what step did you exactly to make it run? The documentation is quite poor. Thank you very much :-)

Comment: Most likely kontrol environment variables are not set.